# Paypal Recurring Payment from MySQL and PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring

I am looking for a way to use PHP and MySQL to keep track of a few products and sell them on my website. I have found the following code online and wish to edit it to make it for recurring payments (paypal subscriptions) instead of single payments. I am not sure what to change for recurring payments. I have read over the PayPal Developer site but there it doesn't show code for what I need. Can anyone help?

Here is the SQL for products:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8         COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 'LavaBasic', 1.99, 1),
(2, 'LavaStarter', 2.99, 1),
(3, 'LavaAdvanced', 4.99, 1),
(4, 'LavaFlow', 5.99, 1);
```

And here is the PHP on the page where I am displaying products:

```
<body>
    <?php
        //fetch products from the database
        $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products");
        while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
        {
    ?>
    <br/>Name: <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
<br/>Price: <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post">

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="Lavastack" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/nitya/paypal_integration_php/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/nitya/paypal_integration_php/success.php'>


    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"   src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

    </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

I am trying to find what to make changes to so that the prices I have listed on the SQL will be recurring for that amount instead of a one time payment. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank everyone in advance.

Comment: You just need to adjust the button parameters to turn the button into a subscription button instead of a buy now button.  Take a look at the [PayPal Standard variables documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust the button parameters to turn the button into a subscription button instead of a buy now button.  Take a look at the [PayPal Standard variables documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) for more details.

Specifically, you'll change this...

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

to this...

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
```

And then you can refer to the [recurring payments / subscriptions section](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU) of the docs to see what the other params are that you would need to use for the amount per period, the period itself (ie. week, month, etc.)  For example, instead of "amount" you would use "a3".